# Facebook like box and comment box not showing any more

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, facebook-likebox

I have following code on http://septicsecurity.com/facebook.html

**It used to work, but does not work any more.** I do not understand why. What happened and what can I do to make it work again?

**UPDATE - I just found out that it works after I threw out the old cash and reopened the browser(s)**
I might also have something to do with that I updated the FB Manage Permissions page and took away any Country Restrictions.

**UPDATE UPDATE** - I'm a moron. I could not see it because I had installed a new app (DNT+) on FireFox that blocks social and ad networks from following you around the net. Subsequently it took away the FB like and comment box.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <meta name="author" content="paulk">

    <title>Facebook</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=161799263843988";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<!-- FACEBOOK START -->
<div style="float:left;margin-right:18px;">
    <div class='fb-like-box' data-href='http://www.facebook.com/pages/Septic-Security/209608059122157' data-width='380' data-show-faces='true' data-stream='true' data-header='true'></div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
    <div class='fb-comments' data-href='http://septicsecurity.com' data-num-posts='5' data-width='380' style='border:1px solid silver; height:588px;'></div>
</div>
<!-- FACEBOOK END -->

</body>
</html>
```

The floating divs above are just to position the like box and the comment box next to each other, I have tried to strip the page of all extra code like that and also just trying to show like box *or* comment box but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not see it because I had installed a new app (DNT+) on FireFox that blocks social and ad networks from following you around the net. Subsequently it took away the FB like and comment box.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the page you linked, I see the Like Box and the Comment Box, side by side. (I'm using Chrome.) Did you make any changes to the code, or did it literally just stop working one day? What specific failure are you seeing, and what browser are you using?

This might also be pertinent: I think that I read that FB has changed their like-box recently; and they have more changes that will be taking effect on October 3:

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#october-2012

Specifically, some Open-Graph functionality for the like buttons won't work any longer (nor will the Live Stream plugin and several other bits,) so you (and I, and everyone else) may have to update our FB like button code Real Soon Now.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that it actually did work, I just couldn't see it because of a newly installed FireFox app.